# How to find the last filled-in cell in a row?

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc

I have the following data sheet. It has a row of dates, where every date has an `A` and a `B` value. I would like to find the last filled-in `B` value for that range.

In the following screenshot, I would like a formula which can calculate the contents of the `LAST A` column for every row.

[image: Screenshot demonstrating an example data set.]

Please note I do not want to merely find the last filled-in cell. For row `5` that would be `C5`, while the last `B`-value would be `B5`, or 6.

Comment: Note: @Scott Craner posted an answer but deleted it, presumably because his answer was for Excel.    Expressions such as `=AGGREGATE(14,3,A1:A5*(A1:A5>0),1)` do not work in LibreOffice.  However `=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A5>1)` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the following formula normally in `G3` and fill down.

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();SUMPRODUCT(MAX(COLUMN($A3:$F3)*($A3:$F3<>"")*($A$2:$F$2="A")))))
```

[image: G3 equals 5]

This uses `SUMPRODUCT` in a tricky but important way.  It forces `MAX` to calculate as an array formula, evaluating each cell in A3 to F3.  In this formula, that is its only purpose -- we did not use `SUMPRODUCT` to add or multiply.

Alternatively, it can be entered as an [array formula](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Array_Functions#What_is_an_array_formula.3F) without `SUMPRODUCT`.  However, array formulas are difficult to work with, so I recommend the first version.

```
{=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();MAX(COLUMN($A3:$F3)*($A3:$F3<>"")*($A$2:$F$2="A"))))}
```

Documentation: [Using Arrays](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Using_Arrays), [INDIRECT](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#INDIRECT), [COLUMN](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#COLUMN).